# How should I handle a new position that isn't the same as what I was offered?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

I've recently taken a job with a new employer. My understanding when accepting this position was that I would be working as a Java developer, but my manager has assigned me to a .net developer role. I am interested in Java, and not .net development. I asked my manager to move me to a Java developer role, but he told me that I had to wait six months first.

How can I handle this situation professionally?

Comment: He puts me to work in .net but am interest to work in Java ..when he appoint me he told tht i want to be work in java.. now his behavier is totally changed .. wt should i do wheater shall i stay in .net or wt to do

Comment: yep! he redirects me by telling  put u in java after 6 months ..he dont evven knw how to respond

Comment: Was there any agreement on working on a specific technology (Java, in your case)? As far as I know, business requirements keep changing and companies usually do not commit to the employee on the details like language of code. It is considered as 'part of your job' to work on different technology. If you are truly unhappy, try to find projects within the company in your area of interest and talk to the manager directly, instead of going to the HR person.

Comment: ty guys here HR ,Manager,Testing all r one person

Comment: @BAP your english is very hard to read due to the many abbreviations and/or spelling mistakes. I suggest you start by writing correct english. Being a fresher, professional appearance in communication is a key feature.

Comment: I just completely rewrote this question to reflect my understanding of the situation based on these comments, and to make it understandable. If I made any mistakes, go ahead and edit it, but try to keep it readable.

Comment: @DavidK: Since this question is older, wouldn't that question be a dupe of this one?

Comment: @GreenMatt Good catch. This question just appeared on the feed with a very low score, which has since changed. I think because the linked question and answer has more votes and an accepted answer that this one should still be closed. I'm open to listen to mods, and maybe this should be a Meta question.

Answer (score 6):

If you feel that this is a [bait-and-switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bait-and-switch) operation, and you're uncomfortable with it, then pursue new employment immediately.

Furthermore, if you've only been with this job for a few days or weeks, then don't feel obligated to even mention it at interviews.

If you've had the job for a bit longer, then be upfront with interviewers and tell them that the job was not what you expected.

---

[@HLGEM's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/93/hlgem) is incorrect to the extent that you're never under any inherent obligation to stick with a job. Bear in mind that the following pieces of advice are *not* mutually exclusive:

1. If a job isn't helping you advance, then seek new employment immediately. If you don't care about your career development, then nobody else will.
2. On the other hand, try not to move around too much because employers will doubt your ability to deliver and finish.

If you're mindful of both, then you'll be just fine.

Comment: I totally agree with Jim here. And indeed, @HLGEM's answer is incorrect.

Comment: I did not say he had to stick with teh job just that as long as he works there he has to do the work he is assigned as well as you can. He is still being paid by these people and blowing off the wrok he doesn;t want to do is stupid and counterproductive.

Answer (score 2):

I was exactly in the same situation a couple of years back. I waited for a couple of months in the new role and when I have realized that I will not be able to enjoy the work anymore then I moved to one of my dream jobs at another firm. Now I am very happy and enjoying both my work/personal life to the fullest.

I think that it is unprofessional to assign work that is not what agreed during the hiring process (interview). If you don't enjoy the work then probably it is difficult to excel in that position. It will also affect your personal life. It is better for you to start looking for your interesting positions in the same firm or at a different one.

I totally agree with @Jim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect that business needs will not change. If he needs you to work in .net, that is where he needs you. How you respond is to do what you are being paid to do. You can tell him that you would prefer to work in Java and ask him if he can find a Java project for you, but until he does, then do the other work to the best of your ability and without complaint. If you do a bad job on the .Net work or become known as a prima donna who complains about everything, they have no incentive to reward you by giving the work that you would prefer.

Through the years I have worked with a lot of projects that weren't my first choice (and sometimes with people I disliked). That is just how business is. The needs of the business take precedence and the needs are fluid, you need to adapt to what the need of the moment is. And you know what, I learned a lot that came in useful on later more interesting projects from the ones I didn't want to be on at first or from the people I didn't want to work with.

An attitude that 'you only want to work on what you want to work on' is a career limiting move. Get rid of it now.