# Company misrepresented my job position -- is it unprofessional to leave after nine months?

Tags: career-development, job-change, reputation

I am currently in my first job, working for a large company. During the job interview, they told me a lot of lies about my job position. Once I started, I realized that my actual responsibilities were completely different from what the company said during the interview.

I've talked with my boss about my aspirations, and my problems about this job, some months ago with no result.

Now, after nine months I've received a good job offer from a smaller company. I would really like to accept, but I would like to know if this change can ruin my reputation with future employers and HR staff.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on some of the issues?

Comment: even if they tell you the truth you can change job if find something better for your career goals. So the lies only make it easier to make the desicion.

Comment: The issues are related to the thing I'm doing. I've been hired as a professional and specialized worker and I'm on completely different things like organize meeting and stay in contact with external consultancy people to monitoring some problems.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28254/actual-work-is-different-than-expected-decision-to-be-made) and [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/how-should-i-handle-a-new-position-that-isnt-the-same-as-what-i-was-offered?lq=1)

Comment: I've known a lot of people in my industry, myself included, who have been in this position.  Sometimes it's not that lies were told, but that the scope changed drastically in ways that were out of the control of the parties responsible for the hiring.  Other times.. yeah, it was lies.  It happens.  Prepare your resume, find a new position and move on.

Comment: @ScrapingInfinity not my case, they just hired me than told me the real situation :(

Answer (score 4):

> I would really join this new workplace but I would like to know if
>   this change can ruin my reputation to future HR peoples.

"Ruin" is the wrong word here.

You will likely be asked why you left so soon after starting your new job. You'll just have to answer why, without slamming your company too much.

Something like "I learned that the actual job wasn't what I thought I heard during the interview." is a good place to start. Try to find ways to expand on that without directly calling them liars. Try to be as professional as possible.

Companies are reluctant to hire folks who they think are job-hoppers. But that conclusion doesn't usually happen after just one job.

> This is my first job, I've talked to my boss about my aspirations and
>   my problems about this job some months ago with no result.
>
> Do you have some advice?

Continue to work as hard as you can in your current job, while you search for your next one.

Make sure to ask more questions during your interviews so that you can find a job that's a keeper. You don't want to have two short-term jobs on your resume if you can avoid it.

You could ask to speak with a potential peer during the interview process. That's a good way to find more about the "real job" that is in store for you.

And of course use your professional network to try to get as much "inside information" about the company as possible before you interview and particularly before you accept any offer.

Comment: As to how to paint the reason for leaving, I've always found that explaining how, once I began working there, the career path of the job was not what I expected.  I then briefly explain the path of the job and then explain the career path I was wanting (which will often strongly relates to the job I'm applying for).  You don't have to mention anything about the job itself being deliberately misrepresented.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to suggest you to have a talk with your manager or a senior, then I read this:

> I've talked to my boss about my aspirations and my problems about this
>   job some months ago with no result.

So, I suggest you hand over your resignation, and start negotiating with that other company.

> I would like to know if this change can ruin my reputation to future
>   HR peoples.

**No**, it would not affect your reputation, cause it is your first job and you can explain honestly about what had happened, and about how the role at their(the new) company would help you achieve your ambitions/aspirations.
And they will definitely understand.

Comment: Except the order is to negotiate with the new company, have a job offer in hand, and only THEN hand over a resignation.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I think I would quit the first company by calling from my desk of the new employer on Day 1.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship: No, you don't do that.  You stay professional.  Zero-notice ragequitting should be reserved for really egregious situations, which this one isn't.